# Rails aws dynamo insert into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I use this code to insert into dynamo db:

```
require "aws"

AWS.config(
    access_key_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    secret_access_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    region: 'eu-west-1'
)

dynamo_db = AWS::DynamoDB.new


table = dynamo_db.tables['mytable']
table.hash_key = [:string, :string]

# add an item
table.items.create(id: '12345', 'foo' => 'bar')
```

Everything is ok, the data is inserted but I still get this error:

> missing hash key value in put_item response

What did I missed? According their [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html) seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.hash_key = [:string, :string]`

needs be changed to `[:name_of_hash_key, :type_of_hash_key]`, for example

`table.hash_key = [:id, :string]`

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

I think that you need to remove the call to `table.hash_key` and specify the `hash_key` when you create the table. Here's an example from the documentation from the version of the API you seem to be using (V1)

```
table = dynamo_db.tables.create(
  "MyTable", 10, 5,
  :hash_key => { :id => :string }
)
sleep 1 while table.status == :creating
```

See the documentation on this page:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html          # V1